# Terminal command to remove unknown file

Tags: command-line, rm

What is the command to remove unknown file from terminal.

Edit after following answer:  Example: I have two files `يا مهدي-  Times-يا محمد  Events.html` `مهدي Events.html` how do i only first file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case is really simple. Just use the following command:

```
rm -i *Times*Events.html
```

There is no problem if you have more files like '*Times*Events.html' in the same directory; Because of the switch `-i` (for *interactive*) you are asked every time if you really want to remove it.

Another way is to switch between Arabic and English languages when you are writing in terminal.

Comment: What if I have two files `يا مهدي- -يا محمد Events.html` and `مهدي Events.html`? I need to remove only the first one?

Comment: ِ@ZafrullahSyed I specified clear: *There is no problem if you have more files like '*Times*Events.html' in the same directory; you are asked everytime if you realy want to remove it*. And this because I used `-i` option in `rm` command.

Answer (score 0):

A simple

> rm *Events.html

will do the trick.
**BE CAREFULL**
This will also remove any other file you have whose name is terminated by "Event.html" string.